# How can I listen for a "Menu Opened" event in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, events, menu

I want to some processing when a menu is opened in a qt application, e.g. when the `File` menu is clicked.

I am not talking about handling an action from the menu like clicking `File->Save`. I only want to know when `File` was clicked.

There is signal called `aboutToShow()`. But is there some sort of event we can listen for and process in an event filter? Would it possible or nessecary to create a custom event?

Comment: Why is an event preferred over a signal?

Comment: I guess it might not be nessecary, but I have been appending a logger to an application and so far I have managed by logging when an event goes through the event filter. E.g. When the window is moved or minimised etc. I suppose more importantly I would prefer to know that the menu "```isShown```" rather than ```aboutToShow```

Comment: Does the `visible` property give you what you want?

Comment: I went ahead using the signal for now thanks